# Android check GestureOverlayView not empty

Tags: android

I have code to save GestureOverlayView to file like this

```
    try {
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureOverlayView.getDrawingCache());

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/gesture.jpg");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);

        fos.close();

        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to check GestureOverlayView content, when this is empty then save is cancel.

What code that I need?

Answer (score 3):

This line of code will let you know if the GestureOverlayView has a drawable

```
    if(gestureView.getGesture()!=null && gestureView.getGesture().getLength()>0)
    {
//has drawing
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have validated gesture view  empty using following code:

```
if(gestureView.getGesture()!=null && gestureView.getGesture().getLength()>0)
{
   //has drawing`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(gestureView.getGesture()!=null && gestureView.getGesture().getLength()>0)
{
   //has drawing`enter code here`
}
```